# VBA changing active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where in the VBA it goes off opening other spreadsheets and temporarily setting these to the active `worksheet`.

However, I have a loop and at the end of the first iteration I need to set the active worksheet to be the original one which started the VBA module. I cannot set a new `Workbook` object to open the original, because the original is still open in the background and it says its already open.

My problem is that I need to change the active `Workbook` to the original one, when I never had a workbook object to refer to it???

```
'Original workbook is active implicitly

'loop begins

'change active workbook to something else


'Need to change back to original workbook here- but don't have a VBA workbook object

'end of loop
```

Comment: For what reason are you changing the active workbook? Can you not refer to the other workbooks explicitly without changing the active status?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `ThisWorkbook` which will refer to the original workbook which holds the code.

Alternatively at code start

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

*sample code that activates all open books before returning to `ThisWorkbook`*

```
Sub Test()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks
    Wb2.Activate
Next
Wb.Activate
End Sub
```